# How to state timezone in DateTime to get date and month

Tags: c#

How can i get date and month of timezone ('UTC')

In php:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

echo date("jn");
```

But how can i get it in c#?

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dM")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DateTime.UtcNow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on
>   this computer, expressed as the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

```
DateTime td = DateTime.UtcNow():
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, any concept of the "current" time zone is tied to the operating system settings of the machine that the code is running on. There are some Win32 apis for changing the time zone, but I don't recommend using them. Not only are they not "thread-safe", but they aren't "process-safe" either. The time zone setting affects everything running on the machine.

That said, I'd be curious what your use case really is. If you are in the position to set the timezone per thread, then you are probably in a position to not rely on the local setting at all. You can probably make use of the conversion methods on TimeZoneInfo instead.

For example, say you were looking for the current time in some other time zone. You might be looking for the ability to do this:

```
using (TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone = ...  )
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
}
```

But instead you should simply convert from UTC where appropriate:

```
var now = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
                   DateTime.UtcNow, "some other timezone id");
```